# pioneer2dx teleop in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

http://robotics.usc.edu/ros/category/stacks/p2os says that a working drivable urdf model of the Pioneer2dx for gazebo/rviz is released.

How can I teleoperate a pioneer robot in a Gazebo simulation?
I could visualize the pioneer robot both in gazebo and in rviz using,

roslaunch p2os_urdf pioneer3dx_urdf.launch

roslaunch p2os_urdf pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch

What should I do next?

By the way, after launching from above launch files, after few minutes, the robot automatically starts moving. Why is that?

Thank you in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11254/pioneer2dx-teleop-in-gazebo/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2011-09-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-09-24**:
@Peshala : After those 2 commands, my robot did not move at all ! ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try the [pr2_teleop package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_teleop), or the [erratic_teleop package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/erratic_teleop). Both of these allow you to issue cmd_vel messages via the keyboard. The erratic_teleop node provides linear x and angular z commands, which are all that you need for the Pioneer.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-09-28**:
Unfortunately, I could not recreate that error for you. Try using "rostopic echo /cmd_vel" and see if anything appears. Maybe you could also use rxgraph to check if anything is publishing to the wrong topics.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-09-27**:
Thank you for your reply. However, as I mentioned, the robot starts moving automatically and it cant be controlled from key board.